# Rollback Transaction using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

So basically I have a small events section for a Rails site I'm working on, short story is you upload an event with an image, date, title, description, etc. etc. The image is uploaded using carrierwave and hosted on Amazon S3 via fog. However, while I'm able to get the written information uploaded and saved, the image does not appear in the index view due to something I believe is happening here during the `POST` action:

```
   Started POST "/events" for ::1 at 2016-11-03 13:17:50 -0700
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CxSgDMK1+fsZfLNImzK/KV1TwTaRX7uhHq0OJEbbEZzTyC18SAEy7laK+mIVdd/jjzB5ZJ5qGs3jfYl2Yhi3mQ==", "event"=>{"title"=>"asdfdsfdsf", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8f09f48f90 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/vg/xzxwmlt12qz27hmcwq5d_q4r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20161103-73790-1pl5juy.JPG>, @original_filename="054.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[image]\"; filename=\"054.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "image_cache"=>"", "date"=>"2012-01-06", "time"=>"dsafdsafa", "body"=>"sadfadsfasfdf", "public"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered events/_form.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered events/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered subscribers/_form.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 112ms (Views: 86.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms))
```

With that in mind I feel that the image upload process should have failed all together however, when I upload the image the first time and the `render :new` action occurs you can see the uploaded image except if I leave this page (even after saving the image in again) that image wont appear in the index view where it is supposed to:

[image: Imgur]

> First thing to mention is that the `image` property of the `Event`
>   object is coming up nil upon upload.

**Image Uploader**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class EventImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  process :resize_to_fill => [400, 225]
  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

**New Event View & Form Partial**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-font">
      <div class="divider-vertical">
        <h1>New Event</h1>
         <p>Guidelines for Event:</p>
         <ul>
           <li>Leave the proper location and date.</li>
           <li>Explain the event in under 35 words.</li>
           <li>Explaine the pricing.</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 form-font">
       <h1>Add an Event</h1>
       <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { event: @event } %>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

*Form Partial*

```
<%= form_for event do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a title" %>
  </div>
  <% if event.image? %>
     <div class="form-group">
       <p>Current Image</p>
       <%= image_tag( event.image.url, style: 'max-height: 100px;' ) %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :date %>
        <%= f.date_field :date, class: 'datepicker form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :time %>
        <%= f.text_field :time, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter the event info" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :public, class: 'checkbox' do %>
      <%= f.check_box :public %> Public event
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

**Relevant Excerpt from Events Controller**

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.user = current_user
    authorize @event
    if @event.save
      redirect_to vpaadmin_path, notice: "Event was saved successfully."
    else
      puts @event 
      flash[:error] = "Error creating event. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    authorize @event
    if @event.update_attributes(event_params)
      redirect_to vpaadmin_path, notice: "Event was updated successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error saving event. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    authorize @event
    if @event.destroy
      redirect_to vpaadmin_path, notice: "Event was deleted successfully."
    else
      redirect_to vpaadmin_path, error: "There was an error deleting the event, please try again."
    end
  end

  private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :date, :body, :public, :image, :time, :image_cache)
  end
```

Wouldn't most of the views be irrelevant considering the Event.image property is coming up nil anyway.

Please request any other files you'd like to see.

Comment: The view(s) that isn't displaying the image and uploader class would be helpful.  What happens if you fetch the object in console?  Is the file retrieved?

Comment: Joe Essey, the image is coming up nil, I also made sure my AWS keys were up to date as well just in case there were any issues there. I'll add the views now.